# Data is not displaying in BirtReports while calling from while jboss AS 7.0.1 server

Tags: mysql, jboss7.x, birt

Data is not displaying in BirtReports while calling from   jboss AS 7.0.1 server

But when i am running the file in reportdesign the data is displaying?

what i understood is i want to copy jdbc driver into birt viewer
what is the location to copy it?

Answer (score 0):

Download Link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjava5123binjar.htm
download and place the  jar file in WebViewer/Web-Inf/lib folder

Comment: you get error or just a  blank screen ? Instead of viewing report in birt viewer try to run report in java and see what happens..

Comment: not getting any error showing the birt reports empty. reports not taking data from database. but while i am running reports in java the data is displaying.

Comment: have you tried any report in viewer which do not use data set i.e. which simply shows some text elements etc?  reports containing only static text elements  work fine? if not then its not data connectivity issue and problem  might be with your viewer!!